# Make function like confirm

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simulate the confirm function of javascript. But it doesn't work. Where am I making a mistake?

```
function func(){
    $('body').on('click', '.true', function() {
        return true;
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.false', function() {
        return false;
    });
}


function test(){
    var r = func();

    if(r==false){
        alert('false');
        return false;
    }

    alert('it works');
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdxbwyLf/)

Comment: What happens if you click the button twice? Will it return twice? Also, you can't represent an *asynchronous action* with a *synchronous `function`*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`confirm` *halts the codes execution* of the browser, until a button gets clicked. That's why `confirm` can return *synchronously* and behave like a *regular function*. You cannot halt the browsers execution from within JS, so this is entierely impossible (or if you do, the user cannot input anything).

You could however create and return a promise (which can then be resolved asynchronously):

```
 function func(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $('body').once('click', '.true', function() { // Only listen to *one* click instead of keeping this listener forever
        resolve(true); // resolve the promise if clicked
    });

   $('body').once('click', '.false', function() {
     resolve(false);
   });
  });
}
```

That can then be used as:

```
 async function test(){ // has to be async, so that the execution can be haltet
   var r = await func(); // halts till click

   if(!r) { // reads "if not r"
    alert('false');
  } else alert('it works');
}

test();
```

[Read On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: this can then be used as: ?